# .net program impersonates native binary

Tags: .net, reverse-engineering

I was given an executable for testing. It was said that programm is written in .NET c#. But ILSpy couldn't open it: *This file does not contain a managed assembly.* Is there a way that .net executable can be packed with some kind of protector or exe is simply native programm? Thank you.
UPD: In case when programm is packed, how to find out protector name (I'am sure that some popular was used) and make the code readable again?

Comment: _"Is there a way that .net executable can be packed"_ - if I say "yes", is your question answered? Can you perhaps [edit] your question and ask the question that will really help you further?

Comment: @CodeCaster, I never did actually reversing of native programms, except for few crackmes in the past. So I think you know better than me what is needed to go further in this case.

Comment: Buying a book on how executables and obfuscation work, maybe? :) This is a bit broad to explain.

Comment: If obsucated code was easily de-obfuscated, the obfuscator didn't do its job. Many obfuscation programs wrap a binary around the managed code, acting as a bootstrapper. They can even encrypt the contents in such a way that you have to do a memory dump to even see the decrypted code. If this is a truly obfuscated library, you will need a lot of effort to see what is inside. As @CodeCaster says, you should do a little reading on the techniques and theory involved before attempting this yourself.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I mean that is this file is protected, then probably some popular protector was used, like themida or similar. So maybe there's a way to unpack it using similar software without actually reversing.